# Isabelle: commands/ syntactic local variables / syntactic abbreviations

Tags: isabelle

I want to write multiple formulas that include a common variable combination, but i am lazy so i want to have a syntactic variable.

```
IE "a + b + c"
"a + b - c"
"a + b + e - a"
```

Instead of writing "a + b" each time i would like to be abled to write something like:

```
X == a + b

"X + c"
"X - c"
"X - e - a"
```

With the same functionality as LaTeX has it with the \include command. it should still identify "X - e - a" as "b - e".

Comment: Do those variables appear in function definitions, theorems or in proofs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The short answer

The default way is to use `abbreviation`. This introduces a purely syntactical abbreviation that will be expanded during parsing. If the `a` and `b` in your case are fixed terms like `1+2` and `3+4`, you can simply do this:

```
abbreviation "X ≡ (1 + 2) + (3 + 4)"
```

and then write `X + c`, `X - c`, `X - e - a`. Note also that abbreviations are folded back before printing, i.e. `(1 + 2) + (3 + 4) + 5` will be printed as `X + 5`. If you don't want this, you can use `abbreviation (input)` instead.

Also note that `5 + (1 + 2) + (3 + 4)` will *not* be printed as `5 + X` and is *not* syntactically the same as `5 + X` because addition associates to the left: `5 + (1 + 2) + (3 + 4)` is `(5 + (1 + 2)) + (3 + 4)`, whereas `5 + X` is `5 + ((1 + 2) + (3 + 4))`.

You can also use `definition`; this introduces a new constant called `X`. You can unfold the definition using the theorem `X_def`. But from your question, I gather that you don't want that.

## What about variables?

It is not entirely clear from your question, but I guess your situation is something like this:

```
lemma foo: "P (a + b + c)"
(* some proof *)

lemma bar: "P (a + b - c)"
(* some proof *)
```

In that case, you cannot use an abbreviation as above, since `a` and `b` are variables and you cannot have free variables on the right-hand side of an abbreviation (or a definition). You can, however, locally fix the variables in an anonymous context:

```
context
  fixes a b :: "'a :: ring_1" (* change this type if necessary *)
begin

abbreviation "X ≡ a + b"

lemma foo: "P (X + 3)"
(* some proof *)

lemma bar: "P (X - 3)"
(* some proof *)

end
```

The lemmas `foo` and `bar` are then exported with the fixed free variables `a` and `b` generalised to schematic variables in the usual fashion. However, `thm foo` will be printed as `?P (X (X ?a ?b) 3)`, which is a bit strange, and, in fact, any occurrence of `+` will be printed that way, so doing `abbreviation (input)` is a good idea in any case.

## A note on hygiene

Polluting the global namespace with a name as general as this is typically considered bad style. An alternative using a local definition would be this:

```
context
  fixes a b :: "'a :: ring_1"
  fixes X defines X_def[simp]: "X ≡ a + b"
begin

lemma foo: "P (X + 3)"
sorry

lemma bar: "P (X - 3)"
sorry

end
```

Here, `X` is not merely a syntactical abbreviation, but a new constant whose definition must be unfolded. However, by declaring the definition a `simp` rule, this unfolding will be done automatically. It will, however, not be re-folded automatically, so you will never see `X` in the output after using the simplifier on it.

Upon exiting the context, the definition will be unfolded everywhere and disappears, giving you the lemmas you want.